# Internal Inconsistency Exception with custom navigation items in *some* versions of iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uinavigationitem

Alright so I've run in to a weird issue and I'm here to see if anyone can help explain this to me.

**Background**

My app is targeted to support iOS 8.
All of my navigation bars are embedded in a `UINavigationController`, and each bar is set up as follows (more or less) in `viewDidLoad`

```
let newNavItem = UINavigationItem()
    newNavItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButtonItem
    newNavItem.rightBarButtonItem = addBarItem
    newNavItem.title = "Home"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setItems([newNavItem], animated: false)
```

**Problem**

When the user registers for the first time, they are segued to a screen that is designed to allow them to choose a profile picture to upload, or to choose a university, depending on their method of registration (with Facebook, or not). In all of my iOS 9 testing, the following segue to my Home screen, which has a navigation bar with buttons added to it like above, this works fine. The buttons are set up and respond as expected. However, with at iOS 8.0.2 and iOS 8.1, when the user goes through this segue a `NSInternalInconsistencyException` is thrown, with the error that

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot call
>   setItems:animated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a
>   controller.***'

However, and here's the weird part, this issue doesn't occur in iOS 8.4, and as I said I have not run into it at all with iOS 9. I have yet to test 8.2 and 8.3, but without doing so, I'm still unsure of why some versions of iOS crash with this exception, while others do not. Hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Well I have found a solution to the problem, and it involves changing the above code for every `NavigationBar` that I have to be changed to what's below:

```
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(menuButtonItem, animated: true)
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(addButtonItem, animated: true)
self.title = "Home"
```

I'm putting this here in case someone else comes along with the same problem and doesn't have a solution, but I'm still confused as to why the exception is thrown only on certain versions of iOS, and if someone could tell me why, that would be great.